# parameter n in p.adjust function in R

Tags: r, probability, p-value

I'm quite confused about the n parameter in p.adjust function.

p.adjust(p, method, n = length(p)) where n could be changed. but the default is length of p as stated in the documentation.

So in my understanding, if I didn't include the n parameter is the same as I list n to be the length of p in that function.

However I run into a problem, I got 2 different adjusted p values based on no n included in that function and setting n = length(p).

Anybody could let me know why happen like this? And which adjusted p value should I trust? Thanks so much!!!!!!!

Comment: just to make the question be more clear, I set the method  = 'fdr' there. Thanks!

Comment: HI! You will need to add mcve as defined here https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for people to find the problem. It is not well stated as of now. However, CrossValidated is also not supposed to answer software issues so you will likely see your question closed as off topic. In that case ask the question with an mvce on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

What I suspect is that there are NAs in your set of p-values. In this case, you should exclude these from the number of tests you are doing. `p.adjust()` takes them out by default if you do not specify `n` argument. When you adjust your p-values you should, of course, exclude any invalid p-values.

If this is not the case, can you include your example?